RollupError: "createRequire" is not exported by "node_modules/node-stdlib-browser/esm/mock/empty.js"
I have a Vue 3 project that is built with Vuetify and Storybook. It is set up with Vite. This project is used to build a package that's supposed to be consumed by our other projects. When I'm trying to run build, I'm getting the following error:

error during build: RollupError: "createRequire" is not exported by
"node_modules/node-stdlib-browser/esm/mock/empty.js", imported by
"node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/index.mjs". file:
C:/Users/kogan.anatoliy/GitHub/Jcdc_Standards_Vue3/node_modules/@vuetify/loader-shared/dist/index.mjs:1:9 1: import { createRequire } from 'node:module';

If I add @vuetify/loader-shared to 'external' under Build rollupOptions, build is successful. But when I import this package into another project and run dev there, Im getting a blank page and a console error:

Uncaught TypeError: (0 , import_node_module.createRequire) is not a
function at chunk-DTHMMC23.js?v=8019bd45:303:54

Here's my vite.config.ts:
 // Plugins
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from "vite-plugin-vuetify";
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";
import { resolve } from "node:path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls },
    }),
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
    }),
    nodePolyfills({protocolImports: true,}),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".mts", ".json", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".vue"],
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["vuetify"],
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/main.ts"),
      name: "MyComponents",
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: "My-components",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ["vue", "@vuetify/loader-shared"],
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/sass/variables.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
});

I read somewhere that this is due to the built-in Node module ('node:' ) type of import that is used in Vuetify's loader-shared and not allowed by Vite.
Would appreciate it if anybody could suggest a solution.
